# How to connect to the project jar package for its class without any IDE, using only the command line?

Tags: java, jar

How to connect to the project jar package for its class without any IDE, using only the command line?
I'm going to connect the JNA to use external methods.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Please add more infos to the question

Comment: @AndréSchild I have jar file, which is a library of classes. Namely, that is JNA. How to use it? I don't work with any IDE, I work with command line.

Comment: Just add the jar's to your classpath...?

Comment: @AndréSchild How to do this? I don't know. Write it as answer, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -cp lib\*; Sample.java
java -cp lib\*; Sample
```

Where folder "lib" contains jar library, "Sample" is main class